# Google analytics events showing up in Real Time, but not in Behaviour

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have implemented GA events for downloads, and they seem to work fine when looking into Real Time data. However, in the behaviour section the events show no results. I read that it could take up to 48 hours to process data in the behaviour section, but after almost two weeks it's still empty. Also double checked all the filters (date, labels, etc.).

What makes it even stranger, is that I see results from de day I took the code with the events implementation into production. The day after it went blank.

Comment: did you ever solve this? How?